# How do you put 4 buttons side by side (2 on top, 2 on bottom) for Android?

Tags: android, xml, button, imagebutton

I am trying to create 4 image buttons so that their positioning is like this: 
top left  --- top right

bottom left --- bottom right

I am using a LinearLayout if it matters. Here is what I got so far (all 4 have the same code):

```
<ImageButton
    android:background="@drawable/pic"
    android:id="@+id/multiButton"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:text="cool"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

I have also tried setting the layout_width to "fill_parent" and the layout_height to "wrap_content" but that still did not help.

Comment: Have you tried using a grid layout?

Comment: Learn basic usage of all layouts in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy this xml into your layout and you'll see all the buttons aligned in 4 different corners.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @user2403836 did it help you? If so, mark it as an answer as your question is  still open and got 6 different opinions. Selecting one will make it easier for people with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Relative Layout as the parent of those 4 buttons, then in the Buttons you can use, e.g for the Bottom Left Corner, something like below. You can apply the same for Top Right, Top Left and Bottom Right by just playing around with the similar arguments.

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in the linear layout requires nesting of linear layout (which is why relative layout is recommended) The pseudo code is as follows:

```
<Linear-layout-parent>
  orientation: vertical
  <Linear-layout-a>
    orientation: horizontal
    align: parentTop/wrapcontent
    <btn1 align:left/>
    <btn2 align:right/>
  </Linear-layout-a>
  <Linear-layout-b>
    orientation: horizontal
    align: parentBottom/wrapcontent
    <btn3 align:left/>
    <btn4 align:right/>
  </Linear-layout-b>
</Linear-layout-parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using RelativeLayout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<Linear-layout-parent>
  orientation: vertical
  <Linear-layout-a>
    orientation: horizontal
    align: parentTop/wrapcontent
weightsum="100"
    <btn1 align:left
weight="50"
height="wrapcontent"
width=0dp/>
    <btn2 align:right
weight="50"
height="wrapcontent"
width=0dp/>
  </Linear-layout-a>
  <Linear-layout-b>
    orientation: horizontal
    align: parentBottom/wrapcontent
weightsum="100"
    <btn3 
weight="50"
height="wrapcontent"
width=0dp/>
    <btn4 
weight="50"
height="wrapcontent"
width=0dp/>
  </Linear-layout-b>
</Linear-layout-parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/child"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:context="com.example.stack.MainActivity" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/child1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/child2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```